# Rails installation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I fail to install rails properly for some reason. `gem install rails` says everything is fine but I cannot use it due to some missing gemfile. What am I doing wrong?

I am working on a mac Sierra.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]

$ gem install rails
Fetching: rails-5.1.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-5.1.4
1 gem installed

$ rails -v
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

$ gem list rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

jquery-rails (4.3.1)
less-rails (3.0.0, 2.8.0)
rails (5.1.4)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3, 2.0.2, 2.0.1)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails_12factor (0.0.3)
rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
rspec-rails (3.7.2)
sprockets-rails (3.2.1, 3.2.0)
twitter-bootstrap-rails (4.0.0, 3.2.2)
```

Comment: Do you have a file like `$HOME/.irbrc` or something like this? It looks like someone call `bundle`

Comment: I have a `~/.irbrc` but bundle is not used in it.

Comment: Found a work around. I created an empty `Gemfile` in the directory where I was trying to write `rails new testApp` and then it worked.

Comment: It's strange any way because Gemfile isn't necessary for running `rails` command

Comment: That is what I thought aswell. Hence the question. Could it be an issue with multiple rails versions?